# Building accumulator for lazy lists in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, lazy-evaluation

I defined a simple lazy list of all integers from zero:

```
(define integers-from
  (lambda (n) 
    (cons n
          (lambda () (integers-from (+ 1 n))))))

(define lz (integers-from 0))
```

I also coded an accumaltor that gets a lazy list as a parameter

```
(define lz-lst-accumulate
  (lambda (op initial lz)
    (if (null? lz)
        initial
        (cons (op (head lz) initial)  
              (lambda () (lz-lst-accumulate op (op initial (head lz)) (tail lz)))))))
```

Does this accumaltor answer the format of lazy lists?
Here is a simple test of the accumulator:

```
(define acc (lz-lst-accumulate * 1 lz))
(take acc 4)
=> '(1 2 6 24)
```

`take` is a helper function that creates a list from the first `n` elements of a lazy list:

```
(define head car)

(define tail
  (lambda (lz-lst)
     ((cdr lz-lst)) ))

(define take
  (lambda (lz-lst n)
    (if (= n 0)
        (list)
        (cons (car lz-lst)
              (take (tail lz-lst) (sub1 n)))) ))
```

Comment: Please add your definitions of `head`, `tail` and `take`.

Comment: @uselpa i added the definitions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `lz-lst-accumulate` you calculate once `(op (head lz) initial)` and then also `(op initial (head lz))`. This is inconsistent; both should be the same and actually calculated only once, since it's the same value:

```
(define lz-lst-accumulate
  (lambda (op initial lz)
    (if (lz-lst-empty? lz)
        initial
        (let ((val (op (head lz) initial)))
           (cons val
              (lambda () (lz-lst-accumulate op val (tail lz))))))))
```

It works in your example with numbers only because you use the type-symmetrical operation `*`. With `cons` it wouldn't work.

Other than that it's OK. `lz-lst-accumulate` is usually known as [*left fold*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) ([`scanl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl) in Haskell, actually, since you produce the progression of "accumulated" values, `foldl f z xs = last (scanl f z xs)`).

---

re: your version of `take`, it is forcing one too many elements of a stream. Better make it

```
(define take
  (lambda (lz n)
    (if (or (<= n 0) (lz-lst-empty? lz))
      (list)
      (if (= n 1)
        (list (car lz))      ; already forced
        (cons (car lz)
              (take (tail lz) (sub1 n)))))))
```

so that it only forces as many elements as it has to produce, and not one more (which might be e.g. divergent, like `(/ 1 0)`, invalidating the whole calculation for no reason).

***That way, the counter-example in [SRFI 41](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41/srfi-41.html)*** (of `(take 4 (stream-map 1/ (ints-from-by 4 -1)))`) ***will just work*** (it calculates `(1/4 1/3 1/2 1/1)` without forcing  `1/0`, which the usual version of `take`, like the one you're using, would do).

Comment: can you say i wouldn't work with cons? because i tried and it work as expected...and thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: it's my pleasure, you're welcome. :) I mean both `(cons a b)` and `(cons b a)` can't produce same results.