# Accumulator for infinite streams

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm trying to implement an accumulator for an infinite stream. I've written the following code but it's running into an infinite loop and failing to terminate

```
(define (stream-first stream) (car stream))
(define (stream-second stream) (car ((cdr stream))))
(define (stream-third stream) (car ((cdr ((cdr stream))))))
(define (stream-next stream) ((cdr stream)))


(define (stream-foldl func accum stream)
    (cond
         [(empty? stream) accum]
         [else (stream-foldl func (func (stream-first stream) accum) (stream-next stream))] ))
```

I've written up a few tests to demonstrate what I'm trying to implement

```
(define (natural-nums)
   (define (natural-nums-iter n)
   (thunk
   (cons n (natural-nums-iter (+ n 1)))))
   ((natural-nums-iter 0)))

(define x (stream-foldl cons empty (natural-nums)))
(check-equal? (stream-first x) empty)
(check-equal? (stream-second x) (list 0))
(check-equal? (stream-third x) (list 1 0))

(define y (stream-foldl (curry + 1) 10 (naturals)))
(check-equal? (stream-first y)  10)
(check-equal?  (stream-second y) 11)
(check-equal?  (stream-third y)  13)
```

Here's a trace of my stream-foldl function

```
>(stream-foldl
  #<procedure:cons>
  '()
  '(0 . #<procedure:...9/saccum.rkt:25:0>))
()>(stream-foldl
  #<procedure:cons>
  '(0)
  '(1 . #<procedure:...9/saccum.rkt:25:0>))
(0)>(stream-foldl
  #<procedure:cons>
  '(1 0)
  '(2 . #<procedure:...9/saccum.rkt:25:0>))
(1 0)>....
```

I believe I'm failing to properly set a base case, thus never terminating from the recursion call

Comment: cf. [Building accumulator for lazy lists in Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23247790/849891). of course folding an infinite list takes infinite time. one way to overcome this is to produce the progression of interim reduced values (as I show in my answer there).

Answer (score 3):

Fold is supposed to look at every element in the stream, then produce a result based on those elements. With an infinite stream, it is no surprise that the fold does not terminate (how would you be able to look at every single element in an infinite stream?).

What you can do:

Produce a finite stream out of the infinite stream. [`stream-take`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream-take%29%29) can be used for that. Example implementation of `stream-take`:

```
;; Returns a stream containing the first n elements of stream s.
(define (stream-take n s)
  (cond ((zero? n) empty-stream)
        ((empty? s) (error "Stream is shorter than n")
        (else
          (delay (stream-first s)
                 (stream-take (- n 1) (stream-rest s)))))))
          ; Note: 'delay' is the same as the 'thunk' in your code.
```

Then, fold the finite stream either using your implementation of fold, or [`stream-fold`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream-fold%29%29).

Comment: Can you elaborate how to get finite stream from infinite stream with `stream-filter`? Will not it just stuck forever in `stream-empty?` then?

Comment: @PetSerAl Yes you are right. My mistake. Edited the answer.